# Angular + RequireJS: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, single-page-application

Well friends, I am having problems using the Angle with RequireJS. Below is the code structure to facilitate:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/',
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        route: {
            deps: ["angular"]
        },
        app:{
            deps:['route']
        },
        controller:{
            deps:['app']
        }
    },
    paths: {
        //Libery
        angular:            'assets/js/lib/angular',
        route:              'assets/js/lib/angular-route',
        //APP
        app:                'app/app',
        //Controller
        controller:         'app/controller/controller',
    },

    deps: ['controller']
});
```

**app.js**

```
define('app', ['angular', 'route'], function (angular, route) {
    var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
    {
       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

       $routeProvider

       .when('/', {
          templateUrl : 'app/views/home.php',
          controller  : 'home',
       })

       .when('/sobre', {
          templateUrl : 'app/views/sobre.php',
          controller  : 'sobre',
       })

       .when('/contato', {
          templateUrl : 'app/views/contato.php',
          controller  : 'contato',
       })

       .otherwise ({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });    
});
```

**controller.js**

```
define('controller', ['app'], function (app) {

    app.controller('home', function($rootScope, $location){
       $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
    });

    app.controller('sobre', function($rootScope, $location){
       $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
    });

    app.controller('contato', function($rootScope, $location){
       $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
    }); 

});
```

And the problem is **Can not read property 'controller' of undefined**
In RequireJS believe that the dependencies are correct!
Thank U.

Comment: `app.js` doesn't seem to be returning anything

Comment: I will analyze! thank you

Comment: Do not shim your modules since they are well defined RequireJS modules. Shim is only to use for external libraries that are not designed to be AMD compatible. Like angular, but not app and controller.

Comment: You're right. thanks floribon

Comment: Thanks guys! Problem solved, but now with the following error **[$injector:modulerr]**. Already includes the angular-resource, but the error persists